# Shortcut for [return] key

Tags: keyboard, shortcut

How do I make a keyboard shortcut for the `return` key? For example, if I pressed `~` it would press `return` for me. I'd like to do this without applescript. Is this possible, or will I have to buy a functioning external keyboard because my return key doesn't work!

Comment: While there is an accepted answer below and this question was a pretty good academic exercise, I have to put on my "operations hat" on for a sec and say that in the name of productivity, you should get a new keyboard.  This is like trying to go from Miami to New York by way of Alaska.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Download, install and start [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/). In the menubar open (Karabiner icon)-> Preferences. Enter "Return" in the search field and choose one of the preconfigured key codes:

[image: Karabiner]

By editing the *private.xml* in *Misc & Uninstall*  you may add any additional  key or (not already used) key combination and choose this one instead.

Comment: Karabiner can't download without an admin username and password. Is there any way to just get the app, and not the DMG?

Comment: @ALX You can't download it or you can't install it?

Comment: No, I'd need the ZIP, not the DMG to open it... forgot my admin password and don't want to go through the steps to retrieve or reset it.

Comment: @ALX The admin password is obligatory because AFAIR you have to install a launch daemon and a launch agent.

Comment: Darn... Well, I guess I'll have to go back and retrieve my password

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without being admin on your Mac, and with a simple creation of a key binding file.

Create a file (on a standard install, the directory `KeyBindings` doesn't exist):

```
mkdir ~/Library/KeyBindings
```

containing the following remapping:

```
$ cat >~/Library/KeyBindings/DefaultKeyBinding.dict <<end_of_file
/* my keybindings */
{
        "\U007e" = ("insertNewline:") ;
}
end_of_file
```

`\U007e` means Unicode of the standard `~` character (== `0x7e`). You can't use `"~"` in this dictionary because it means <kbd>option</kbd>.

(I suggest to avoid the use of the character `~` because it is used
in command environnment to mean `${HOME}`. For example if you want to
use <kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>, put `"~/"` in place of `"\U007e"`.)

And restart your session.

To suppress this key binding, just remove this file:

```
rm ~/Library/KeyBindings/DefaultKeyBinding.dict
```

and if you dont need it, remove also the useless directory:

```
rmdir ~/Library/KeyBindings
```

and restart your session.